# Multiple select inputs handle using python

Tags: python, html

How to get multiple select inputs using python using a form?

```html
<select name="files" multiple="">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What python library are you using for scrapping? What exactly do you want to find? All selected values?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Please show what you have done to achieve that task in python. Or if you want to know how to achieve that, please be specific. Also give a read to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It'll help the community to better understand your requirements. Thanks!

Comment: Using request.form.getlist(), I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use "request.form.getlist('name')",
It will give you all the submitted inputs together as a list